# How to produce this Aufbau/Hund diagram in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix, chemistry

How to produce this Aufbau/Hund diagram in LaTeX?

[image: hund-aufbau]

I would prefer Chemfig, but TikZ seems a better fit.

Comment: Look into the documentation of stackengine ;)

Comment: Thank you. I've looked at the documentation at http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/stackengine/stackengine.pdf but couldn't find an example complete enough.

Comment: Welcome! What did you get from the incomplete examples? Pretty much all questions should include a minimal example demonstrating the problem you're having. For diagrams, this is usually 'this is how far I managed to get, but I can't do the next step' and the code gives the done bit, the question asks for the next bit. (Actually, this isn't very usual - there are lots of do-it-all-for-mes - but, ideally it would be ubiquitous.) Or you may get lucky and find a procrastinator who finds your diagram an attractive challenge.

Comment: Isn't this basically an arrow or two arrows with a circle around it/them? Why do you think you need TikZ or chemfig at all?

Comment: Thank you @cfr for taking your time to comment my question. In reality, I wanted to learn something new today and wondered what was the right way to start with this sort of diagram. However, I understand your concerns. I will try to be more specific, next time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With TikZ:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}
\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 0 and 9mm,
          C/.style = {circle, draw, thick},
every label/.style = {align=center}
                    ]
\node (c1) [C,label=below: orbitale pieno]
                                {\rotatebox{90}{$\rightleftarrows$}};
\node (c2) [C,right=22mm of c1] {\rotatebox{90}{$\rightarrow$}};
\node (c3) [C,right=of c2]      {\rotatebox{90}{$\roghtarrow$}};
\node[label=below:elettreoni spaiati\\ con spin paralleli,
      fit=(c2) (c3)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:** 
An solutions with TikZ arrows (defined by library arrows.meta) and use of small pictures `pic`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, fit, positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
     node distance = 0 and 9mm,
        CAA/.pic = {\draw[-Stealth,thick] (-1mm,-3mm) -- + (0,6mm);
                    \draw[Stealth-,thick] ( 1mm,-3mm) -- + (0,6mm); 
                    \node[circle, draw, thick, minimum size=8mm,
                          node contents={}, label=below:#1];
                    \coordinate (-center)   at (0,0);
                    \coordinate (-top)      at (0, 4mm);
                    \coordinate (-bottom)   at (0,-4mm);
                    },
         CA/.pic = {\draw[-Stealth,thick] (0mm,-3mm) -- + (0,6mm);
                    \node[circle, draw, thick, minimum size=8mm,
                          node contents={#1}];
                    \coordinate (-center) at (0,0);
                    \coordinate (-top)      at (0, 4mm);
                    \coordinate (-bottom)   at (0,-4mm);
                    },
every label/.style = {align=center}
                    ]
\pic (c1) at (0,0) {CAA={orbitale pieno}};
\pic (c2) at (3,0) {CA};
\pic (c3) at (4,0) {CA};
\node[label=below:elettreoni spaiati\\ con spin paralleli,
      inner sep=0pt, fit=(c2-top) (c3-bottom)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could choose another arrowhead (may be visit `arrows.meta` library documentation). Oh, I just see you used glyphs; which by the way, don't seem aligned :S

Comment: @Zarko What you have done is impressive, thank you. I wasn't unsure if that needed tikz only, or also tikz-matrix, or if that was doable with chemfig.The stackengine suggestion was cool but maybe it would have been more difficult to lay out the same diagram.

Comment: Thanks @Manuel for your arrow.meta library suggestion, I was just wondering if there were any other arrow styles!

Comment: @GiancarloDiMassa Yes, but that solution works if you use TikZ arrows (which I would choose). This is just using TikZ to create a circle around a rotated glyph used in mathematics.

Comment: Yes I've seen that, it is clever.

Comment: @GiancarloDiMassa, my solutions doesn't use library `matrix`. First solution is simple, new one is slightly more sophisticated, arrows are drawn with TikZ. In it even linrary`positioning` is not used (but it can be used on similar way as it is in the forat solution). For solution using package `chemfig`I'm not right person (I never use this package).

Comment: I'm reading the manual of Tikz now, it really seems a not so hard to understand graphic system after seeing your example. Right, the second one is more difficult to iterate over and over: probably I'll follow @Manuel advice and use arrow.meta.

Comment: But my second example use `arrows.meta` library! Frankly said, I don't understand, what you mean with last comment. Definition of `pic` you can move to `tikzset` placed in preamble of document, that it is available to all TikZ pictures in document and it is not need to be repeated in any picture.

Comment: Sorry, you are right, my last comment is wrong and I've typed it without thinking enough! I looked at the lengthy syntax and tought arrow.meta was some sort of glyphs library, it indeed is not, it just seems to add various styles of arrow caps to lines. Also, the hint at the top that declared library usage should have been very clear.

Comment: Did you write the code by hand or use some assisting GUI?

Comment: All my code I wrote "by hand". I use WinEdt ads editor.